# How to resolve "Make sure the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm# is correct" error in wxWebView (wxWidgets)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, wxwidgets

I am using wxWebView for showing our page content and when I don't have any content for the page, i.e. page is blank, I see the following error:

[image]

I have my own file system handler class derived from `wxWebViewHandler` like below and in `GetFile` function, I set the content of page. Everything works fine except when page does not have any content. Maybe I should return something else.

```
struct WxHtmlFSHandler: public wxWebViewHandler
{
  WxHtml* dst_;

  WxHtmlFSHandler( const wxString& scheme, WxHtml* dst ): wxWebViewHandler( scheme ), dst_( dst )
  { }

  wxFSFile* GetFile( const wxString& uri ) override;

  ~WxHtmlFSHandler()
  {
    dst_ = nullptr;
  }
};


...

if( dst_ && !uri.empty() )
  {
    if( uri.Contains( dst_->defaultURL_ ) )
    {
      // load the page's content 
      //if( !dst_->currentPage_.empty() )
        return new wxFSFile( new wxMemoryInputStream( dst_->currentPage_.data(), dst_->currentPage_.size() ),
          uri, wxT( "text/html" ), dst_->currentAnchor_
  #if wxUSE_DATETIME
          , wxDateTime::Now()
  #endif
        );
      ...
   }
```

I am also using IE engine for now.

```
#if wxUSE_WEBVIEW_IE
  wxWebViewIE::MSWSetEmulationLevel( wxWEBVIEWIE_EMU_IE11 );
#endif
```

I am using wxWidgets 3.1.5 on Win 10.

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Igor I expect to see nothing! A blank page without any content. But those errors come

Comment: the page is actually not blank - its incorrect. And the engine notifies you about that. Just doing what you did should be a proper way

Comment: @Igor Is it not better to give some basic tags like `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` instead of a simple space?

Comment: probably. But you shuold check if it will do that. If it will - then yes - it will be better (at least maintenance-wise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is when the page content is empty. So I just tried to add a space char to my memory input stream like below and see the effect. It seems working!

Basically I replaced

```
return new wxFSFile( new wxMemoryInputStream( "", 0 ),
          uri, wxT( "text/html" ), dst_->currentAnchor_
#if wxUSE_DATETIME
          , wxDateTime::Now()
#endif
);
```

with

```
return new wxFSFile( new wxMemoryInputStream( " ", 1 ),
          uri, wxT( "text/html" ), dst_->currentAnchor_
#if wxUSE_DATETIME
          , wxDateTime::Now()
#endif
);
```

and now page is blank and does not show anything as expected. I don't know whether this hack is good or even correct, so if anyone has a better answer, please let me know.